# Creating Animation for search

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I am writing an animation for my search button, so when the user clicks on search I want to make a transition on my button and then move it to left and push the search view on it's back. I am trying to use the following code:

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation   animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
animation.repeatDuration = 1000;
animation.duration = 30;
animation.additive = YES;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:360];
[self.SearchButton.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];

[CATransaction begin]; {
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 delay:2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
            [self.SearchButton setFrame:CGRectMake(self.slideMenuButton.frame.origin.x, self.slideMenuButton.frame.origin.y, self.SearchButton.frame.size.width, self.SearchButton.frame.size.height)];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 delay:10.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
                [self.navigationController presentViewController:Search animated:YES completion:nil];
            }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                [self.SearchButton setFrame:CGRectMake(searchOrigin.x, searchOrigin.y, self.SearchButton.frame.size.width, self.SearchButton.frame.size.height)];
            }];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [self.SearchButton.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
        }];
    }];
}
```

Each animation is working correctly but I want them to follow each other so the feeling of movements be good. It means I want the button to do a transition and then move to the new point and the new view push to my view by following that.
It would be appreciated if you help me or give me any idea so I can implement that.

Comment: You should start new animations in completion blocks of previous animations.

Comment: @Losiowaty Thanks for your reply but I don't want one animation to finish and then the next one starts, I want them to be nested and follow each other with a delay